# Windows 8.1 Store App Static Resource Converter - The resource could not be resolved

Tags: c#, xaml

```
 <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}" 
                  SelectedValue="{Binding Selected, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                  Height="Auto" 
                  Width="Auto" 
                  VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border BorderBrush="Aqua" BorderThickness="2">
                        <StackPanel Width="Auto" 
                                    Height="Auto" 
                                    Background="Blue">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding colId, Converter={StaticResource StringFormatConverter}, ConverterParameter='Collection ID: {0}'}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description, Converter={StaticResource StringFormatConverter}, ConverterParameter='Description: {0}'}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

**C# Code String format converter class**

```
 public sealed class StringFormatConverter : IValueConverter
 {
   public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,  string language)
   {
     if (value == null)
      return null;

     if (parameter == null)
      return value;

     return string.Format((string)parameter, value);
   }

  public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
    string language)
  {
   throw new NotImplementedException();
  }
}
```

The above class should take care of the formatting that I want to display in the UI, but I am getting 'The resource could not be resolved'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your page/user control xaml which contains the listview, you have define the convertor as a static resource before you can use it. So if your Convertor is in namespace **dummynamespace** then place this in either :

```
<Page xmlns:common="using:<dummynamespace>">
<Page.Resources>
<common:StringFormatConverter x:Key="StringFormatConverter" />
</Page.Resources>
```

or

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}" 
              SelectedValue="{Binding Selected, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
              Height="Auto" 
              Width="Auto" 
              VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
<ListView.Resources>
<common:StringFormatConverter x:Key="StringFormatConverter" />
</ListView.Resources>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border BorderBrush="Aqua" BorderThickness="2">
                    <StackPanel Width="Auto" 
                                Height="Auto" 
                                Background="Blue">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding colId, Converter={StaticResource StringFormatConverter}, ConverterParameter='Collection ID: {0}'}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description, Converter={StaticResource StringFormatConverter}, ConverterParameter='Description: {0}'}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Comment: Aww okay, I will try that and get back to you.

Comment: Yes, that totally works. Thanks, that makes sense that you need to add a way for the xaml to find the resource.